# Wrong function called after class toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm facing such problem. I have div with class `oldClass` and function that toggle div's class `on click`. When the class changed clicking on div should trigger other function and call alert, however this behavior doesn't appear and it seems like **previous** function is called again. I'm quite new in [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), so what am I missing?

```
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
         $('.oldClass').on('click',function(){
          $(this).toggleClass('oldClass').toggleClass('newClass');

            });
    });

    $(function(){
         $('.test').on('click',function(){
             alert('1111');  
            });
    });
        </script> 
        <style>
        .oldClass {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    .newClass {
        border: 3px solid green;
    }
    </style>
     </head>
      <body>
      <div class="oldClass" title="qwerty">qwerty
    </div>
      <body>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go! You have to subscribe and unsubscribe to events. I'm new to jQuery as well and it might be not the clearest solution, but it works. If anyone can suggest a better solution, you are welcome.

```js
var subNewClass = function () {
    $('.newClass').off().on('click', function () {
        alert('1111');
    });
};

var subOldClass = function () {
    
};

$(function () {
    $('.oldClass').off().on('click', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('oldClass').toggleClass('newClass');
        $('.newClass').off().on('click', func);
    });
});
```

```css
 .oldClass {
     border: 1px solid red;
 }
 .newClass {
     border: 3px solid green;
 }
```

```html
<div class="oldClass" title="qwerty">qwerty</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring [document.ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) twice ... `$(function(){});` is a shortand for `$(document).ready();` and not a javascript function declaration ...

To create a function you should first do `function foo(){ /* content goes here */ };` or `var foo = function(){ /* content goes here */ };` ant then call it whenever you want by writing `foo();`

Read more about JS functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function)

Check this to see how this should work: [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/henser/hyfjo8od/14)

```
  var alertTrigger = function (){

        $('.newClass').on('click',function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('oldClass').toggleClass('newClass');
         alert('1111');  
        });


}

$(function(){
         $('.oldClass').on('click',function(){
          $(this).toggleClass('oldClass').toggleClass('newClass');
            alertTrigger();
            });

   });
```

Comment: I made changes you suggested:http://jsfiddle.net/hyfjo8od/1/  Still behavior is incorrect. On first click on div it should changes its class and change border color to green and it does. On second click it should just show alert and that's all.

Comment: check edited answer (mainly jsfiddle) ... and next clicks? what should it do? nothing or alert the message?

Comment: There should be two states. First state: you click on div - it changes its class to **newClass** and color to green. Second state: click on div - it alerts message,changes its color to red and class to **oldClass**. 
The second function should look like this:
`$('.newClass').on('click',function(){ alert('1111');
    $(this).toggleClass('newClass').toggleClass('oldClass');
        });` 
But I just simplified it, removing class toggle.